# What are the options for Azure Functions to use additional hard drive?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans, azure-managed-disk

I have Azure Functions running in AppService plan (Windows). One of the functions runs some kind of export data from the application and requires quite a lot of disk space. It started to run out of space on disk. Is there any option how to attach a storage (e.g. managed disk, virtual hard drive based on Azure Storage or something like this) so that the Function App could use it? Any samples?

Comment: For Linux Functions you could mount Azure Files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations#mount-file-shares

Comment: But anyway, if you run in App service plan mode, you would have gigabytes of local storage available. If that is not enough, I would start to question whether Functions are the right fit for what you are trying to do (or even if you are not getting close to those limits Functions might not be the right choice) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

Comment: @silent The feature is about to export all user's data. It means collecting various types of data - all uploaded files, converting some internal structures into PDF reports and putting it all into one zip archive that is then uploaded into the BLOB storage and make it available for user to download. What would you suggest for this instead of Functions?